# Creating an Ellipse using PIL in Python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, ellipse

I have already looked around for some time now and tried almost everything. I have contacted my teacher and we just can't seem to figure it out. I am trying to use PIL to create an ellipse with the following code:

```
import PIL.ImageDraw
import PIL.Image

PIL.Image.open('Logo.jpg')
draw = ImageDraw.Draw('Logo.jpg')
draw.ellipse((20,20,180,180),fill='blue', outline='blue')
```

I have already checked and the working directory is set to the correct place with the picture in it. The code spits out the following error:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
E:\Canopy\Merrick_1_4_7.py in <module>()
---> 5 draw = ImageDraw.Draw('Logo.jpg')
     6 draw.ellipse((20,20,180,180),fill='blue', outline='blue')
NameError: name 'ImageDraw' is not defined
```

If anyone has anything thoughts I would appreciate it if you left a comment.

Comment: `draw = PIL.ImageDraw.Draw('Logo.jpg')`

Comment: If you want to use `ImageDraw` you need to do the import like `from PIL import ImageDraw`. Otherwise as it is you still need to qualify `ImageDraw` with `PIL` like @Sraw is saying. You are already doing it on the line before.

Comment: Oh, I feel so stupid. That was a really simple mistake. Anyway thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Now I have another problem. When I run the program it has a different issue with the same line: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'load'

Comment: I haven't changed the code at all except for the PIL.ImageDraw instead of just ImageDraw

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of ImageDraw.draw is an image instance, not a filename.

```
import PIL.ImageDraw
import PIL.Image

im = PIL.Image.open('Logo.jpg')
draw = PIL.ImageDraw.Draw(im)
draw.ellipse((20,20,180,180),fill='blue', outline='blue')
```